# Creating a histogram with .txt file using Python?

Tags: python

Here's the code I tried. It gave me a syntax error highlighting 'data'. Any help? The .txt file has 4 columns if that's of any help.

```
def file():
  file = open('hsp.txt', 'r')
  col = [] data = file.readlines()
  for i in range(1,len(data)-1):
    col.append(int(float(data[i].split(',')[5])))
  return col

def hist(col):
  handspan = []
  for i in range(11):
    handspan.append(0)
  for i in (col):
    handspan[i] += 1
  return handspan

col = file()
handspan = hist(col)
print(col)
print(handspan)
```

Comment: BTW `file` is a keyword in Python, redefining it will lead to many problems debugging.

Comment: Any specific reason you want to define your own frequency distribution function? Numpy and/or Pandas will do it for you

Answer (score 4):

It is because your line

```
col = [] data = file.readlines()
```

should be on two separate lines:

```
col = []  
data = file.readlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it worked for me. 
Hence it is a histogram it yields a dictionary.
Better answers are welcome!

```
import string
def list_from_file(filename):
    myfile = open(filename, 'r')
    data = myfile.read().split()
    col = []
    for word in data:
        col.append(word)
    return col

def myhist(col):
    hist = {}
    for word in col:
        word = word.lower()
        word = word.strip(string.punctuation + string.whitespace)
        hist[word] = hist.get(word, 0)+1
    return hist

col = list_from_file('em.txt')
colf = myhist(col)
print(colf)
```